# StringLength/Minlength validation doesn't prevent user from posting the form with no value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, web

I have the following property on my ViewModel

```
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_StringLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global))]
public string LeagueName { get; set; }
```

If the string ends up being larger than 20 characters the validation will fire and not allow the user to post the form. However, if the field is blank, which means that the LeagueName property has a length of less than 1 it will allow the user to post the form.

I know this is easily resolved by using the Required attribute, but why is the validation not working as expected in this scenario?

Comment: It's by design. What if you wanted a field to except either no input or if there is input then between 3 and 6 characters?

Comment: What makes you think that this is *the expected* behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is by design.

This is the validation logic for StringLength:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
  this.EnsureLegalLengths();
  int num = value == null ? 0 : ((string) value).Length;
  if (value == null)
    return true;
  if (num >= this.MinimumLength)
    return num <= this.MaximumLength;
  else
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, when the string is null `StringLength` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `StringLength` attribute only validates the string length. It only does the validation if the string not null.

Here is the Validation method from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
      this.EnsureLegalLengths();
      int num = value == null ? 0 : ((string) value).Length;
      if (value == null)
        return true;
      if (num >= this.MinimumLength)
        return num <= this.MaximumLength;
      else
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of MVC (5.1 and jquery validate packages) and use `MinLength` attribute instead. See this for details [mvc51-release-notes#Unobtrusive](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Unobtrusive)