# ASP.Net Web API: Allow blank strings in request property that has a MinLength attribute set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a request field defined as follows:

```
[MinLength(9)] [MaxLength(18)] public string Id { get; set; }
```

I would like the user to be able to input a blank string for this field and not have it trigger the Minimum length attribute. Is there some other attribute that I can add for this or do I need to remove the MinLength attribute and do my own, more manual, validation?

Comment: how about writing a custom validator by inheriting the `ValidationAttribute` and overriding the `IsValid` method which then can be used as a data anotation attribute

Comment: As @thanzeel said you'd either have to write a custom validator with the relevant inheritance, or (if that's not an option within your constraints) use an extra variable `public string EnteredId {get; set; }` that directly takes the user input - if it's not null or whitespace you can cast to the `Id` variable which will deal with the min/max length.

Comment: Use [`StringLength`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16211800/11683) instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow a property to be null or a specified length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331839/allow-a-property-to-be-null-or-a-specified-length)

Answer (score -2):

You have just reached your goal,
When user enters a character, `[MinLength(9)]` Will be activated.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.